# In Facebook integration I have to access the url of in which access token is given, but instead I am getting my published url in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following code on Page_Load of facebook_login page in asp.net web application. After redirecting this url I have got the accesstoken in url but when I try to access this current url via HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri it gave the url of app where it is published not the url which is currently in window.

How can I access this access token or userdetails?

```
var uriParams = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                    {"client_id", facebookAppId},
                    {"response_type", "token"},
                    {"scope", "user_about_me, read_stream, email"},
                    {"redirect_uri", "http://apps.facebook.com/appNameHere/"}
                }; 
        StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var current in uriParams)
        {
            if (urlBuilder.Length > 0)
            {
                urlBuilder.Append("&");
            }
            var encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(current.Value);
            urlBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", current.Key, encoded);
        }
        var loginUrl = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" + urlBuilder.ToString();
        Response.Redirect(loginUrl);
```

Comment: If i am not wrong , the problem is you are not able to get AccessToken correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Facebook you can set **call back url** value which should point to your web application. So once you make request to `http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth` and after successfully login Facebook redirect to Callback Url (which is your web application).

Then you have to make call to url : `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token`  something like this:

```
        StringBuilder uri = new StringBuilder();
        uri.Append("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?");
        uri.Append("client_id=" + ClientKey + "&");
        uri.Append("redirect_uri=" + Curl + "&");
        uri.Append("scope=offline_access&");
        uri.Append("client_secret=" + ClientSecret + "&");
        uri.Append("code=" + OAuthCode);

        HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Empty);            
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        req.ContentLength = 0;
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        HttpWebResponse resp;
        try
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            string result = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            string[] resultCollection = Regex.Split(result, "&");
            string access_token = Regex.Split(resultCollection[0], "=")[1];//This is the access token
            //which you want and you can save it to database or some  where for further use.
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;

            //pass on the exception
            throw ex;
        }
```

**UPDATE :**

OAuthCode you can get like this, it is available when after successfully login FB redirect to your web app page

```
OAuthCode = Request.Params["code"];
```

Header you can pass empty like `String.Empty`

Comment: Above code which I have given, I am getting access code but only in url after login when my app page is open and i try to find current url it gives me https://127.../mypage.aspx instead of the facebook url apps.facebook.com/myapp#access_token=ACCESSTOKEN&expiry

Comment: can u please explain what is OAuthCode and header ? I am also geeting error on this line  HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);

Comment: Why you want facebook url, it is correct that after successfully login it came back to your web application and you are getting access token.

Comment: Also when I pass my url https://127..../mypage.aspx in redirect uri it gives me error on fb page but wheni give the path apps.facebook.com/myPaaName it redirect me

Comment: I just want after login it access my app page and on this page_load i can access the user profile id

Comment: your redirect uri should match with callback url which you set on fb.

Comment: when i tried my above code  with redirect uri testfb.com/mypage.aspx it gives me error. I think I am somewhere wrong in my code because i am unable to redirect on callback page it gives me error Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration code 191

Comment: How can I get the code when I m trying to callback uri it gives me error.. have you had any solution for passing on redirect uri on login page  my redirect url is http://pvrfb.com/thanks.aspx

Comment: have you set testfb.com/mypage.aspx  as call back url in fb also?

Comment: No, my facebook canvas url is my that page which checks the login and after login this page will open my testfb.com/mypage.aspx in facebook iframe, In fb canvas url is my login page and callback url is testfb.com/mypage.aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26439/discussion-between-swati-sinha-and-popeye)